# creating redhat lxc inside redhat host machine

Tags: virtualization, redhat, lxc

I was in the process of creating redhat based lxc in redhat host machine but lxc-create doesn't have any template for redhat. I like to know if there is any feasibility to create redhat lxc in redhat host machine.I have also read about virsh and docker. Virsh is used for host based containers but will it be isolated similar to LXC and have anyone had experience about it. I'm confused whether i can configure separate filesystems and network interface for each container in virsh. Please help me with best solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Docker Hub is full of images that can be used with LXC (including redhat images). You can use [dlrootfs](https://github.com/robinmonjo/dlrootfs) to download the redhat image directly from the Docker Hub and then use it with LXC.

Hope that helps

Comment: thank u..i will try this but i went ahead with docker itslef..profiling of each container is not enough in docker compared to lxc..will return to lxc if you mentioned was feasible.

Answer (score 0):

For Red Hat-based systems, including RHEL, CentOS, and Fedora, you might want to use Podman, which is designed as a drop-in replacement for Docker and provides a similar interface. Podman can create and manage containers, and it is well-integrated with Red Hat's ecosystem.

Here's a basic example of how you can create a Red Hat-based container using Podman:

> podman run -it --name my-container registry.redhat.io/rhel8:latest /bin/bash

In this example, registry.redhat.io/rhel8:latest is the Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 container image. You can replace it with an appropriate image for your needs.

Now, regarding your question about virsh, it is typically used for managing virtual machines (VMs) rather than containers. virsh is associated with the KVM/QEMU virtualization stack. If you are looking for containerization and isolation, it's more common to use Docker, Podman, or other container runtimes.

In terms of isolation, containers created with Docker or Podman are designed to be lightweight and share the host kernel while providing process and filesystem isolation. Each container gets its own filesystem and network namespace, which helps in achieving isolation similar to virtual machines.